# macOS Mojave local snapshots

Tags: macos, terminal, time-machine

I just upgraded my Mac to Mojave and can no longer see any backup volume mounted even though Time Machine is enabled, my disk has enough space, and therefore should be used to store local backups..

```
tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

Displays:

```
/com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-12-04-104303
```

So there are snapshots available but I cannot see the internal content of it through the terminal as I use to by typing `ls /volumes/Mobilebackups`

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it is my impression that the local snapshots are not made available as a file system. For the ordinary user, the time machine interface provides the only access to the local snapshots. But if there is an API for snapshot access (and I hope there is), it should be technically feasible to write a [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) filesystem for snapshot access. (Sadly, I have neither the expertise nor time to try such a project myself.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mojave stores Time Machine snapshots as APFS snapshots.

You can list these snapshots using `tmutil`:

```
% tmutil listLocalSnapshots /
[…]
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-12-04-123456
```

These snapshots are not exposed anywhere in the filesystem by default, but they can be mounted manually using `mount_apfs`:

```
% sudo mkdir /Volumes/snap
% sudo mount_apfs -o ro -s com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-12-04-123456 / /Volumes/snap
```

Make sure to unmount the snapshot when you are done with it:

```
% sudo umount -f /Volumes/snap
```

Comment: ty a lot worked just wondering why is there only 1 snapshot listed? it ain't supposed to make several snaps a day ?

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? I was always wondering what can I do with localsnapshot, other than tmutil and TM GUI.

Comment: @Raska Weird -- I've got a whole bunch of local snapshots. Is your hard drive almost full? Maybe they're being pruned.

Comment: @amdyes `man tmutil` has some information. Not much, though.

Comment: @Raska I think the number of snapshot relates to whether you have checked 'Back Up Automatically'

Comment: @duskwuff well back up auto is enabled, i got 120go of free disk space..it's rly frustrating :(

Comment: @amdyes "Time Machine saves one snapshot of your startup disk approximately every hour, and keeps it for 24 hours." so dunno

Comment: @duskwuff mount_apfs: mount: Operation not permitted any idea ?

Comment: exactly what i was looking for,  now i can search my snapshots - see: https://gist.github.com/nlitsme/dc309d3ba72a3de24da4f6c5bcce136e

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work in Big Sur? I get 'mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: No such file or directory'.

Comment: **Update for macOS Catalina onwards**: You need to grant Terminal Full Disk Access, or access to the directory you want to mount the snapshot on. Also, use `/System/Volumes/Data` instead of `/` in the `mount_apfs` command.